# Phalcon Routing not working in Nginx

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I just moved from development to production. I realized my routing is not working in the production environment. I am using a LEMP stack.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

This is my nginx configuration.

```
server {

listen   80;
server_name localhost;
charset utf-8;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
set $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/ppl/public';
root $root_path;

try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
    root $root_path;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Here is my routing code snippet.

```
$di->set('router', function () { $router = new Router();

$router->add(
    '/list/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Listing',
        'action'     => 'detailed',
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 2

    )
);   
$router->add('/', array(
    'controller' => 'Listing',
    'action' => 'home'
)); 

$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
return $router;
},true);
```

I am able to access the controller and respective actions via url.

Is there anything important that i am missing?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it is a case sensitive issue

In the routing code snippet, changed

Listing to listing makes the app work